# Add Curly Brackets to Rtf

Tags: rtf, richtext

If I have a text that includes curly brackets, how can I put them in rtf without it thinking I'm trying to Start or end a block?
Example Text:
new int[] { 5, 2 }
And second question - are there more special characters like that? (I already know that in order to include a backward slash you got to put two: \ instead of )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. Use the \uN to enter a character by its unicode value N. If you enter curly brackets like this, It won't consider them as part of the code, but part of the text. Note that for some reason the character you insert using \uN takes place instead of the next character so treat the syntax as if it is \uNX while X being any character you don't need. The unicode value of { is 123, } is 125 and \ is 92.